# Logical and pattern to hide/display components in React render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

After reading quite a lot of React code, I've come to notice this pattern to toggle rendering of a component in the React render method.

```
{ CONDITION && <Component /> }
```

This makes very little sense to me.
Either this is not a logical and but another operator entirely; why not anything else then && in that case?
Or it is a logical and, the lazy evaluation only evaluates(renders) the second clause if the first is true. If this is the case, it feels like an ugly hack we shouldn't use.

What does that syntax mean, and what is the reason behind it?

EDIT:

From the answers it is clear that it is a logical conjunction operation. That it works due to how lazy evaluation works in JS. And that it is used because it is more practical than the alternatives.

This is still very unsatisfying to me. An operation that is as clearly defined as AND([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Definition)), should not, in my world at least, change definition due to lazy loading(which is there because of performance, and performance alone). I guess Javascript has these inconsistencies everywhere though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`A && B`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) evaluates to:

- `B`, if `A` is truthy, or
- `A` otherwise.

If you try to render the value `false` or `null` or `undefined` in React, then nothing will be rendered.

Therefore, `{ CONDITION && <Component /> }` will either render nothing, if `CONDITION` is falsy, or `<Component />` otherwise.

---

One reason that I can think of for using this syntax is the fact that `{ ... }` needs to contain an expression, and `if-else` is a statement. You could use `if-else` outside the JSX you want to render and return either one component or another (and that's a common approach as well), but you can't do that if you need to render something conditionally somewhere inside.

Comment: So it's a logical and after all. I agree that it's more practical than the alternatives, and it's most likely the reason for its use. I still find it very odd in relation to the definition of a logical and.

Comment: @Johnstedt, you could use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead, which is the JavaScript version of an `if-else` expression, even if you don't want to render anything on the `else` clause: `{ CONDITION ? <Component /> : null }` (this is not common, `&&` is usually preferred in this case), or maybe a separate function in which you can use an `if-else` or anything else you might want: `{ renderComponent(CONDITION) }` (this is a common approach).

Answer (score 1):

This is very popular and accepted syntax to render something conditionally.

```
{ CONDITION && <Component /> }
```

Reason,

1. its easily integrated within JSX
2. you don't have to write additional if--else
3. No need of separate variable to hold JSX element.

In short **`Avoide some boilerplate code`**.

```
e.g. without short-circuit, it should like this.

let ComponentName = ''; //additional variable
if(CONDITION){ // Avoidable if else
   ComponentName =  <Component /> 
}

and then inside render
render(){
   <ComponentName />
}
```

**which add more boilerplate code.**

Answer (score 0):

In simple javascript is weird than other languages

you can find more hacks/logics like `&&`

one of the best what I found on javascript

https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs

```js
let myComment =  true && "This is why I love javascript";
let myPost =  false || "I love javascript";
   
console.log(myPost);
console.log(myComment);
```